# wp_update_post() blank screen

Tags: post-editor, wp-update-post

i am developing in `functions.php` a function which, when a post in a certain category is created/edited, will create also a related page or update it if already exists.

The creation of a new page with `wp_insert_post` works like a charme, but if the page already exists (after `else` statement) and use `wp_update_post` instead, Wordpress returns just a blank screen and doesn't update the post and neither the page.

I can't figure out why, `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` doesn't return any hint.

```
$page_check = get_page_by_title($promo_page_title);
if(!isset($page_check->ID)){
    $new_page = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $promo_page_title,
        'post_content' => $promo_page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_parent' => 27
    );
    $new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
    if($new_page_id){
        update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page_promo.php');
        $pids[0] = $new_page_id;
    } else {
        $e = TRUE;
        wp_die('Error creating promo page');
    }
} 
else {
    $new_page = array(
        'ID' =>  $page_check->ID,
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_title' => $promo_page_title,
        'post_content' => $promo_page_content,
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_parent' => 27
    );              
    $new_page_id = wp_update_post( $new_page );
    if($new_page_id){
        update_post_meta($new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'page_promo.php');
        $pids[0] = $new_page_id;
    } else {
        wp_die('Error updating promo page');
    }
}
unset($promo_page_content);
```

Thanks for your help!